# How to make some part of the data in Firestore inaccessible to my frontend?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have some JSON data in Firebase Firestore. The JSON in that data is being used by both the frontend (React) and backend (Node.js) of my application. But some fields in the stored data should be private and not accessible by the users of the website but still need to be available in the backend.

The stored data is similar to this:

```json
school/school_id/class/student_id = {
  "id": 123,
  "name": "rahul",
  "roll": "1234",
  "privateKey": "345"
}
```

Frontend requires everything but the private key and the backend requires everything. If I give all the data to frontend any user can get access to `privateKey` when visiting the website.

What should I do so that the private key in the JSON is not accessible/visible to the frontend?

What have I tried so far?
Till now, I have not tried anything per say but I have read the security rules documentation and also the documentation to toggle visibillity of the json field. But I dont think none of them would solve the issue. I also have thought to remove the private field from the json and store it in some other way and then access it but this way is not that correct and I dont want to go towards this option!

Comment: You need to set up the security rules: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

Comment: The rules you need are going to be specific to your specific use cases.  There's not enough information in your question to know what you need.  You'll have to learn about rules and what they can do, and map that to your use cases.

Comment: If written documentation isn't your thing, the [Firebase YouTube](https://youtu.be/eW5MdE3ZcAw) and some community channels like [Fireship](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7PUm7LmAOw) cover the topic quite well.

Comment: While your new edit has made some progress in the right direction, you still haven't covered what you have tried so far that isn't working or what authentication strategies you are using (only students see their data? only teachers can see this? etc). Once you have answers to these questions, check the above documentation and then if you are still stuck come back here.

Comment: The private data should only be accessible to the owner/admin .